# Ordenar de puntuacion media de mayor a menor

Tags: javascript, mongodb

¿Como puedo mostrar en orden de nota media el top 10 de peliculasde mi base de datos?

El modelo para dar de alta, editar una pelicula seria el siguiente:

```js
var filmSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    titulo: String,
    tipoContenido: String,
    descripcion: String,
    valoraciones: [
      {
        nick: String,
        puntuacion: Number,
        comentario: String
      }
    ],
    generos: Array,
    numReproducciones: Number,
    premios: Array,
    director: Array
  }
);
```

Función JavaScript, en esta función estoy intentando ordenar la puntuación media por el método de la burbuja, esa puntuación media está en el Array() puntMedia, pero a la hora de intentar ordenarlo con ese Array() me es imposible (creo que al declararlo en la función y ser una variable que no está en la db no lo permite mongo):

```js
exports.view = function(req, res)
{
  Film.find({$where: function(top10)
    {
      var puntAcumulada = 0;
      var puntMedia = new Array();

      for(var j = 0; j < this.valoraciones; j++)
      {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.valoraciones.length; i++)
        {
          puntAcumulada += this.valoraciones[i].puntuacion;
        }
      puntMedia[j] = puntAcumulada / this.valoraciones.length;
      }

      //ORDENAR POR METODO DE LA BURBUJA
      var ordenado = true;
      var aux = 0;

      for(var a = 0; a < puntMedia.length; a++)
      {
        ordenado = true;
        for(var b = 0; b < puntMedia.length-1-a; b++)
        {
          if(puntMedia[b] < puntMedia[b+1])
          {
            aux = puntMedia[b];
            puntMedia[b] = puntMedia[b+1];
            puntMedia[b+1] = aux;
            ordenado=false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  },
  {"_id": 0, "titulo": 1, "valoraciones": 1}).sort({puntMedia: 1}).exec(function(err, top10)
  {

    if(err)
    {
      res.send(err);
    }

    res.json({
      message:'Top 10 films',
      data: top10
    });

  });
}
```

El resultado que quiero seria un top 10 de series de mayor a menor por su puntuacion media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es devolver las 10 ultimas películas teniendo en cuenta la media de sus valoraciones hay otros métodos mas eficaces y con mejores rendimientos, ya que el operador `$where` solo se usa cuando no hay ningún operador de MongoDB que pueda evaluar tu consulta. Ademas de tener otras consideraciones de las cuales pueden que al cabo del tiempo no te sean beneficiosas, como por ejemplo que no se aprovecha de los indices si tuvieras alguno. [(Consideraciones sobre el $where)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html#considerations)

Como solución a tu problema, lo que utilizaría es el método `aggregate`, el cual te puedes alimentar de varias etapas que tiene para obtener el resultado que esperas. Te muestro la query para tu solución:

```
Film.aggregate([
{
    $project:{ // Etapa para limitar los campos de los documentos
        _id: 0
        titulo: 1, 
        valoraciones: { 
                 $avg: '$valoraciones.puntuacion' // Con el operador $avg realizaras la media de todo los subdocumentos del campo valoraciones
        }
    }
},
{
    $sort: {. // Etapa para ordenar los documentos (en este caso, ordena de mayor a menor teniendo como referencia el campo valoraciones)
        valoraciones: -1  
    }
},
{
    $limit: 10. //Limita la salida de los documentos a 10
}
])
```

Espero que te haya ayudado y no dudes en consultar por si necesitas aclarar algún detalle.

Un saludo